# how to configure outbound email as gmail

Tags: civimail, smtp, google

I want to configure my outbound email as gmail.I am new to this.Can you please tell me the steps like what should be SMTP username and password.
Should I mark authenticate as yes/no?

I tried but I am getting this error.
https://www.screencast.com/t/bbageClqaT

Your suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks,
Mohit Thareja

Comment: Your question is really two different questions:  1) How to setup CiviMail (this based on the screenshot you provided, 2) How do I configure CiviCRM's SMTP interface to integrate with Google mail.  You should split this up into two questions, and provide details as to your CiviCRM version and CMS (and it's version).

Comment: Remote SMTP via Google Apps works, but there are **sending limits** and it's **not the fastest** due to network delays. It may be suitable for smaller sites and local dev environments; if you're sending a lot of mail [this question/answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/how-to-configure-civimail-when-using-google-mail/4779#4779) and [this q/a](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/377/how-do-i-configure-smtp-with-starttls/621#621) are worth a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuring CiviCRM SMTP for using Google Mail's SMTP services:

`SMTP Server:     ssl://smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port:       465
Authentication:  Yes
SMTP Username:   <your valid Google mail username>
SMTP Password:   <your valid Google mail password>`

Finally, you likely need to tell Google that you wish to allow this level of access. See here: [support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en](http://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: I used the same settings as provided by you but I am getting this error.
http://imgur.com/a/wx8kj

I enabled other  settings like imap enabled.
Please help me regarding this error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support.Finally I am able to send email

Comment: how did you solve the problem? I also need help on this. Can you share the details?