# Mail-to-Account does not fetch mail,

Tags: civimail, wordpress

I have configured mail-to-activity but when I run the task to fetch mails, I get an error message in job's log (without any details) and this kind of message in IMAP server log:

```
Oct  8 14:00:01 bazylia dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=10.117.113.20, lip=10.117.113.5, TLS, session=<OrpYmpYhbQAKdXEU>
```

This mail is 'kontakt@mydmain.com'.
I have set user name ('kontakt') and password and obviously CiviCRM can connect to IMAP server. 
How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a IMAP password that does not contain weird/special characters. CiviCRM uses IMAP client that provides user password in such a way that my server (Dovecot) returns an information about bad password format/quoting.

I used tcpdump to track this error.

The password was #iCE+&G-UFF"D and I have changed it to alphanumeric ones.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/WhyDoesItNotWork), the most common reason for your error is that your server only accepts STARTTLS connections on port 143.

If this is your situation, then you can either connect over SSL on port 993 if your server allows it, or you can connect using STARTTLS.  Note that there are some caveats to connecting over TLS:  See [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14814) and [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/377/how-do-i-configure-smtp-with-starttls).