# Authentication error when running the "Fetch Bounces" scheduled job:

Tags: wordpress, civimail, email, scheduled-job, bounce

```
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Failure, Error message: A fatal error was triggered: Could not connect to MailStore for bounce@domain.com@imap.gmail.com
Error message: 

An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The IMAP server did not accept the username and/or password: 12345 BAD Failed to parse your command 1234567test.
```

I am using G Suite account and as well as i have configured IMAP.

Please note that the same username and password works correctly for sending mail through SMTP but fails in case of "Fetch Bounces" scheduled job.

But it is not working.

I am working on wordpress Version 4.9.6 and CiviCRM 5.0.1.

Comment: Do you have the "allow less secure apps" setting turned on? https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en

Comment: Yes, "allow less secure apps" setting turned on.

Comment: I have resolve the issue. The issue was appearing due to "email account password having non-alphanumeric characters".

For this solution link is 

https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6921/mail-to-account-does-not-fetch-mail?rq=1