# What should the outbound SMTP configuration be for Office 365 Exchange?

Tags: civimail, core

I am trying to use Office 365 Exchange as the mail transport for CiviCRM, but get this error.

Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.office365.com:587 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.office365.com:587 (Unknown error) (code: -1, response: )]

I have looked at [enter link description here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/377/how-do-i-configure-smtp-with-starttls), and links therein which seemed to indicate that a STARTTLS issue was fixed.

Office 365 Exchange has these instructions for SMTP connections: 
[enter link description here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)

I am running a development system under Windows so don't have a mail server on board, and in any case don't want to overcomplicate things - performance isn't an issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of civi are you using? https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14814 it's fixed on a fairly recent version of civicrm only

Another reason can be the confirguration of your network or your server: can you start a connection on port 587 to smtp.office365.com ?

However, before you spend too much time on it, last time I checked:
- smtp on office365 was limited in volume, ie find at low volume, but won't work for production
- 365 doesn't handle "+" notation, so and email to bounce+something@yourdomain.org won't end up in your bounce mailbox. This is needed to handle bounces in civicrm

so I would recommend you:
if it's for testing purpose, use a gmail account
if it's for production purpose, use an external provider to do the bulk mailing and integrate it with your civi, for instance sendgrid and this extension:
https://civicrm.org/extensions/sendgrid-event-notification-processor

Comment: CiviCRM 4.7.16+, i.e. a pull from the latest master branch.  I saw CRM-14814 that it was supposed to have been fixed, which is why I asked the question.  It is not a production environment and the failure occurs at the Save and Test stage of setting up outbound emails.  In other words, it is not even making the first connection.  I can make a connection on that port using a putty terminal. What am I doing wrong?I have also tested out and concur that VERP doesn't appear to be supported - adding a redirection rule doesn't catch the bounce+ email before it is rejected.